# Active item: adding a class to an anchor with jQuery

Tags: jquery, navigation

My website has a fixed navigation composed of anchors. I want the text to change color when clicked in order to visually represent an active state and therefore, have to dynamically add a class to the link tag.

I guess I need some jQuery! Problem: I am still learning and do not have any idea on how to achieve this...

Here is my HTML:

```
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="menu_border"><a href="#accueil">ACCUEIL</a></li>
            <li class="menu_border"><a href="#projets">PROJETS</a></li>
            <li class="menu_border"><a href="#services">SERVICES</a>/li>
            <li class="menu_border><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could use something such as...

```
$("nav ul").on("click", ".menu-border", function() {
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

Then define the `active` class in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("nav a").bind("click", function() {
$("nav a.active").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active"). 

});
```

Comment: have you defined class "active" for anchor tag?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your smooth-scroll.js file (or whatever you're using) or you can open a script in your current page:

```
//current highlight
$('nav ul li a').click(function() {
    $('nav ul li a').removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

Then add this to your CSS:

```
.current 
{
    color: #ff6600 !important;
}
```

Comment: what if I scroll page instead of clicking on URL?

Answer (score 0):

This is a fix for Alex's, he had a syntax error.

```
 $("nav ul").click( function() {
        $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    });
```